# Index of Child DOM element within Parent

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a pure JS way of finding the offset of a child within it's parent.

Given the below sample:

```
<div>
A 
<br>
short space elapsed, <b>and</b> up into this noiselessness came Ahab alone from his cabin. 

<span>Taking a few turns on the quarter-deck, he paused to gaze over the side</span>
</div>
```

I would get 3 children, a `br`, `b`, and `span`. Each would need to have an offset to the start of the `div` - So the index of how many characters into the div the start of the tag is.
So the `br` would have an offset of 2.

My initial idea was to get all the `children` of the div, then somehow from that be able to easily get an index.

Comment: What do you want is not clear as much.

Comment: why would the first child element have an offset of 2 - even considering it is the second child node, in a zero based language it makes no sense to give it an 'offset' of 2

Comment: `offset of 2` - 2px, 2em, 2cm...? Why 2? `<br/>` is not visible, how you see that offset? Is your offset same as padding/margin? What offset would be for any other childs?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that seeing the HTML would mean we're dealing with HTML, not what the user can see. It would be the index? So how far along in the HTML does the actual tag start. I also said *an offset to the start of the div*. While that could be ambiguous, in my mind it made sense.

Comment: There may be more children than you expect. All nodes below an element are children, not just the element nodes. In this case, there could be 8 or more.

Comment: @RobG Granted - but they will still have an index value withing the top most parent. I still need that.

Comment: @SemiDemented—in that case, you get the children, loop over them and if they're text nodes, count the characters. If they're elements, their index is the current character count. But your index needs to count element nodes and text nodes separately, so an element might be `[0,2]` and it's element children might be `[1, 12]` and so on… It's a fairly trivial loop, or a slightly more complex recursive function.

Comment: @RobG I'd love an example to work off. I assume you're going to be using `childNodes`

Comment: @SemiDemented—that's not how it works. You write the code, others answer questions about it.

Comment: @RobG I think you misread my comment. I asked for an example, not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getChildrenOffset(parent){

        var childNodes = parent.childNodes;
        var childrenLocations = [];
        var offset = 0;
        var tagIndex = 0;

    for(var d = 0; d < childNodes.length; d++){

        var node = childNodes[d];



        if(node.tagName !== undefined){
            // This is a tag
            tagIndex += 1;

            var curLocation = new OffsetData(offset, tagIndex, node.tagName);
            childrenLocations.push(curLocation);

            offset += node.outerHTML.length;

        }else{
            // Just text
            offset += node.length;
        }
    }

    return childrenLocations;
}

function OffsetData(offset, index, tag){
    this.Offset = offset;
    this.Index = index;
    this.TagName = tag;
}
```